# How to properly subclass dict and override __getitem__ & __setitem__

Tags: python, dictionary, inheritance, subclass

I am debugging some code and I want to find out when a particular dictionary is accessed. Well, it's actually a class that subclasses `dict` and implements a couple extra features. Anyway, what I would like to do is subclass `dict` myself and override `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to produce some debugging output. Right now, I have

```
class DictWatch(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        dict.__init__(self, args)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        val = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        log.info("GET %s['%s'] = %s" % str(dict.get(self, 'name_label')), str(key), str(val)))
        return val

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        log.info("SET %s['%s'] = %s" % str(dict.get(self, 'name_label')), str(key), str(val)))
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)
```

`'name_label'` is a key which will eventually be set that I want to use to identify the output. I have then changed the class I am instrumenting to subclass `DictWatch` instead of `dict` and changed the call to the superconstructor. Still, nothing seems to be happening. I thought I was being clever, but I wonder if I should be going a different direction.

Comment: Did you try to use print instead of log? Also, could you explain how do you create/configure you log?

Comment: Doesn't `dict.__init__` take `*args`?

Comment: Looks a bit like a good candidate for a decorator.

Comment: https://realpython.com/inherit-python-dict/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What you're doing should absolutely work. I tested out your class, and aside from a missing opening parenthesis in your log statements, it works just fine. There are only two things I can think of. First, is the output of your log statement set correctly? You might need to put a `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` at the top of your script.

Second, `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` are only called during `[]` accesses. So make sure you only access `DictWatch` via `d[key]`, rather than `d.get()` and `d.set()`

Comment: Actually it's not extra parens, but a missing opening paren around `(str(dict.get(self, 'name_label')), str(key), str(val)))`

Comment: True. To the OP: For future reference, you can simply do log.info('%s %s %s', a, b, c), instead of a Python string formatting operator.

Comment: Logging level ended up being the issue. I'm debugging someone else's code and I was originally testing in another file which head a different level of debugging set. Thanks!

Comment: What is `dict.set`? It doesn't exist. `dict` don't have a `set` attribute.

Answer (score 89):

Another issue when subclassing `dict` is that the built-in `__init__` doesn't call `update`, and the built-in `update` doesn't call `__setitem__`.  So, if you want all setitem operations to go through your `__setitem__` function, you should make sure that it gets called yourself:

```
class DictWatch(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        val = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        print('GET', key)
        return val

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        print('SET', key, val)
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)

    def __repr__(self):
        dictrepr = dict.__repr__(self)
        return '%s(%s)' % (type(self).__name__, dictrepr)
        
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('update', args, kwargs)
        for k, v in dict(*args, **kwargs).items():
            self[k] = v
```

Comment: I have tried your sol, but it seems that it only works for **only one level of indexing (i.e., dict[key] and not dict[key1][key2] ... )***

Comment: d[key1] returns something, perhaps a dictionary. The second key indexes that. This technique can’t work unless that returned thing supports the watch behavior also.

Comment: @AndrewNaguib: Why should it work with nested arrays? Nested array do not work with normal python dict either (if you did not implement it yourself)

Comment: Yes I did not know so :), for nested indexing level `DictWatch(val)` should be returned instead.

Comment: @AndrewNaguib: `__getitem__` would need to test `val` and only do that conditionally — i.e. `if isinstance(val, dict): ...`

Comment: Having to overwrite 5 methods for a simple case feel overcomplicated.  This is why `collections.UserDict` exists. `UserDict` only require to overwrite `__setitem__` to be compatible with `__init__`, `setdefault`, `update`,...

Comment: Subclassing `MutableMapping` or `UserDict` is preferred over subclassing `dict` in most cases. However `UserDict` does not subclass `dict` so if you need the real builtin python `dict` as your parent class, this does not help you. @Conchylicultor

Comment: Does the `update` method take any more argument than a positional argument for the other dictionary that is used to update the first dictionary?

Answer (score 26):

Consider subclassing [`UserDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#userdict-objects) or [`UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#userlist-objects). These classes are intended to be subclassed whereas the normal `dict` and `list` are not, and contain optimisations.

Comment: For reference, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=userdict#collections.UserDict) in Python 3.6 says "The need for this class has been partially supplanted by the ability to subclass directly from dict; however, this class can be easier to work with because the underlying dictionary is accessible as an attribute".

Comment: @andrew an example might be helpful.

Comment: @VasanthaGaneshK https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-list-and-dict-in-python/

Comment: Another reason to use `UserDict`: It makes `copy()` behave correctly.

Answer (score 9):

That should not really change the result (which should work, for good logging threshold  values) : 
your **init** should be :

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs) : dict.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
```

instead, because if you call your method with DictWatch([(1,2),(2,3)]) or DictWatch(a=1,b=2) this will fail.

(or,better, don't define a constructor for this)

Comment: I'm only worried about the `dict[key]` form of access, so this isn't an issue.

Answer (score 9):

As [Andrew Pate's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49499084/241211) proposed, subclassing `collections.UserDict` instead of `dict` is much less error prone.

Here is an example showing an issue when inheriting `dict` naively:

```py
class MyDict(dict):

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    super().__setitem__(key, value * 10)


d = MyDict(a=1, b=2)  # Bad! MyDict.__setitem__ not called
d.update(c=3)  # Bad! MyDict.__setitem__ not called
d['d'] = 4  # Good!
print(d)  # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 40}
```

`UserDict` inherits from `collections.abc.MutableMapping`, so this works as expected:

```py
class MyDict(collections.UserDict):

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    super().__setitem__(key, value * 10)


d = MyDict(a=1, b=2)  # Good: MyDict.__setitem__ correctly called
d.update(c=3)  # Good: MyDict.__setitem__ correctly called
d['d'] = 4  # Good
print(d)  # {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 40}
```

Similarly, you only have to implement `__getitem__` to automatically be compatible with `key in my_dict`, `my_dict.get`, …

**Note:** `UserDict` is *not* a subclass of `dict`, so `isinstance(UserDict(), dict)` will fail (but `isinstance(UserDict(), collections.abc.MutableMapping)` will work).

Answer (score 1):

All you will have to do is

```
class BatchCollection(dict):
    def __init__(self, inpt={}):
        super(BatchCollection, self).__init__(inpt)
```

A sample usage for my personal use

```
### EXAMPLE
class BatchCollection(dict):
    def __init__(self, inpt={}):
        super(BatchCollection, self).__init__(inpt)

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        if (isinstance(key, tuple) and len(key) == 2
                and isinstance(item, collections.Iterable)):
            # self.__dict__[key] = item
            super(BatchCollection, self).__setitem__(key, item)
        else:
            raise Exception(
                "Valid key should be a tuple (database_name, table_name) "
                "and value should be iterable")
```

**Note**: tested only in python3

Comment: Since this is Python 3, I recommend just using `super()` instead of `super(BatchCollection, self)`