# Custom dictionary lookup in Python

Tags: dictionary, python

if I have a dictionary like this

```
>>> d = {10: 3, 100: 2, 1000: 1}
```

I can type something like:

```
>>> d.get(10), d.get(100), d.get(1000)
(3, 2, 1)
```

Though I want that if the given key is not found, the value corresponding to the nearest key respect the given key is returned:

```
>>> d.get(20), d.get(60), d.get(200)
(3, 2, 2)
```

Instead the result in Python is

```
(None, None, None)
```

What's a Pythonic way to implement the behavior I described?

Thanks

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict-and-override-get-set

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can derive from `dict` to change the behaviour of the `get()` method:

```
class ClosestDict(dict):
    def get(self, key):
        key = min(self.iterkeys(), key=lambda x: abs(x - key))
        return dict.get(self, key)

d = ClosestDict({10: 3, 100: 2, 1000: 1})
print (d.get(20), d.get(60), d.get(200))
```

prints

```
(3, 2, 2)
```

Note that the complexity of `get()` no longer is O(1), but O(n).

Comment: This makes lookup O(n) though, so use with care. Perhaps you should give it a different name instead.

Comment: +1 Nice use of min/key, a trivial optimization may be to test for a direct hit. `if key not in self: key = min(...`.

Answer (score 6):

[bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) module allows fast lookup of insertion position in a sorted list.

```
from bisect import bisect_right

def closest_matches(data, query):
    keys = sorted(data)
    return [data[i] for i in (min(map(abs, (keys[p-1], keys[p]))) for p in (bisect_right(keys, k) for k in query))]

>>> d = {10: 3, 100: 2, 1000: 1}
>>> closest_matches(d, [20, 60, 200])
[3, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this recipe [Fuzzy matching dictionary](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/475148-fuzzy-matching-dictionary/).