# Classes vs Dictionaries in Python for storing key-value pairs

Tags: python, class, inheritance, dictionary

I need to define some key-value parameters to configure the behaviour of a class. My requirements are two:

- To be able to process them programatically
- To be able to make more specific configurations that overwrite some of the values.

The natural approach for the first requirement is to use a `dict` (so I can loop over keys, values or items with a `for` loop), but for the second requirement it seems more appropriate to use a class hierarchy and let the attribute lookup mechanism to do the work (plus I get other goodies like being able to use properties for some values).

Is there a way to get best of both worlds?

---

After reading the comments, It does not need to be mutable (I won't be changing the values of an already created instance), it's just for static configuration. But I might need to add new values in a more specific instance.

I think in the end I could just use a `dict.copy` + `dict.update` for the specific instances (I can live without the properties).

Comment: [maybe create a subclass of dict?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict-and-override-get-set)

Comment: For completeness' sake, you could also define a [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) method on your class, but that won't solve the iteration requirement.

Comment: Is it _instances_ or _subclasses_ of your class that are overriding/adding configuration options? And are these options statically defined, or set dynamically?

Comment: @ekhumoro as you know, the difference between instances and classes in python is subtle (as classes are already objects), so I really don't care if I achieve this with one class and different instances or subclassing a base class and not making a single instance of any of them.

Comment: Since your requirements are so loosely defined, it's hard to give a better answer than just `dict(config, **overrides)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use python 3.3 ChainMap is exactly what you want.

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections#collections.ChainMap

It's basically a list of dictionaries and will look for a given key in each one sequentially until a match is found.

Actually, here's the code to use it in 2.7:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/305268-chained-map-lookups/

Comment: that's beautiful, I ended up implementing my own in different languages a few times :)

Answer (score 2):

Somehow along the lines of what suggested in the commment by Fabio, I would remark that the two are not mutually exclusive, given that in Python [nearly] everything is an object (including classes!).

One obvious solution is - again quoting Fabio - subclassing a `dict`. The other would be make your own class starting from the [`collections.abc` containers](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html) (using an [abstract base class](http://docs.python.org/dev/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class) (`abc`) is not a requirement, but would probably the most pythonic way to implement your own container from scratch).

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

is this what you need?

```
class my_dict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self[name] = value

d = my_dict()
d.key = "value"
print d.key       #>>>value

for k,v in d.items():
    print k,v     #>>>key value
```

Comment: This does not help at all with requisite 2; this is just using a `dict` with attribute syntax.

Comment: @fortran can give a example of requisite 2?

Comment: have a mapping like `{'a': 1, 'b':2}` and make another derived from it by changing `'b':3`, or adding `c:4` for example.

Comment: @fortran then dict.update is the way       

maybe this help: dict(d2,**d1)#(d1 overrides d2)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [named tuples](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). See [here](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/collections/namedtuple.html) and the accepted answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python) for a nice introduction to them. Some important points from that answer are:

- They were added in Python 2.6 and Python 3.0, although there is a [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261/) for implementation in Python 2.4.
- Named tuples are backwards compatible with normal tuples

Also, named tuples have a number of useful methods such as `_fields` to get the names of the used and an `_asdict` method which returns an (ordered) `dict` of the named tuple contents.

Comment: Without the OP clarifying a bit with an example it's difficult to say this for sure, (= I might be wrong!) but I take it that the *"To be able to make more specific configurations that overwrite some of the values"* part of the question means that whatever he will end up using, it will have to be something mutable... and named tuples aren't. :-/

Comment: @mac You're right, I was just thinking about the construction of a  configuration structure with named fields, like [argparse.Namespace](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace), assuming that it would be set and then used, not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

```
class Config(object):
    def _keys(self):
        return (name for name in dir(self) if not name.startswith('_'))
    __iter__ = _keys

    def _values(self):
        return (getattr(self, name) for name in self)

    def _items(self):
        return ((name, getattr(self, name)) for name in self)

>>> class Foo(Config):
...     bar = 3
...     baz = 'spam'
...
>>> class Sub(Foo):
...     bar = 4
...
>>> x = Sub()
>>> list(x._items())
[('bar', 4), ('baz', 'spam')]
>>>
```