# Most efficient way to add prefix to Python dictionary keys

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

So I find myself needing to add a prefix to a Python dictionary.

Basically what I want is for the user of this dictionary to be able to add a prefix on instantiation of the dictionary, in which case the dictionary holds the prefix and everytime a new key is added, it prepends the prefix. But I also want mutate the dictionary if for some reason the prefix is not provided or changed, this means that the old dictionary keys need to have the prefix prepended to them while keeping their respective values.

Use case:

Basically I'm finishing up the last apis of the [MWS API](https://github.com/czpython/python-amazon-mws).
I built the api around the idea that every call needed to take specific parameters,
like :

```
def get_report(self, marketplaceids):
    # Here I process marketplaceids which is a python list
    # and send the following to Amazon:

    MarketplaceIdList.Id.1: 123,
    MarketplaceIdList.Id.2: 345,
    MarketplaceIdList.Id.3: 4343

    # By doing this I eliminate the complexity of the arguments Amazon expects
```

Unfortunately the last two apis are harder to implement this way because they make use of a new "feature" Amazon introduced called `Datatypes`.

These "`Datatypes`" are nested structures.
For example:

I want to call the `CreateInboundShipment` action from the `InboundShipmentAPI`,

The action takes the following arguments:

```
ShipmentId - String
InboundShipmentHeader - InboundShipmentHeader datatype
InboundShipmentItems - A list of InboundShipmentItem datatypes
```

the problem happens because InboundShipmentHeader is a datatype that takes another datatype as argument.
In the end Amazon expects the following:

```
ShipmentId=102038383
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipmentName': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.Name': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.AddressLine1': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.City': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.StateOrProvinceCode': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.PostalCode': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.CountryCode': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentHeader.DestinationFulfillmentCenterId': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipmentStatus': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentHeader.LabelPrepPreference': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentItems.member.1.QuantityShipped': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentItems.member.2.QuantityShipped': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentItems.member.1.SellerSKU': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentItems.member.2.SellerSKU': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.AddressLine2': 'somevalue',
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.DistrictOrCounty': 'somevalue',
```

so I want to make it simple for someone to make this call without having to worry about the names of each argument.
My solution is to create a base datatype class and then create the separate datatypes
as classes.

This is what I have so far:

```
class AmazonDataType(dict):
    """
    Base for all Amazon datatypes.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._prefix = kwargs.pop('prefix', '')
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def prefix(self):
        return self._prefix

    @prefix.setter
    def prefix(self, value):
        self._prefix = value
        newdict = {'%s.%s' % (value, key): dictvalue for key, dictvalue in self.iteritems()}
        self.clear()
        dict.update(self, newdict)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        try:
            original_key = self.fields[key]
        except KeyError, e:
            raise e
        if isinstance(value, AmazonDataType):
            value.prefix = original_key
            dict.update(self, value)
        else:
            newkey = self.prefix + original_key if self.prefix else original_key
            dict.__setitem__(self, newkey, value)

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Props to Matt Anderson (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2390997/389453)
        """
        for k, v in dict(*args, **kwargs).iteritems():
            self[k] = v


class InboundShipmentHeader(AmazonDataType):
    fields = {
        'name': 'ShipmentName',
        'address': 'ShipFromAddress',
        'fulfillment_center_id': 'DestinationFulfillmentCenterId',
        'label_preference': 'LabelPrepPreference',
        'cases_required': 'AreCasesRequired',
        'shipment_status': 'ShipmentStatus',
    }
```

then instead of doing

```
somedict = {
    'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipmentName': 'somevalue',
    'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.Name': 'somevalue',
    'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.AddressLine1': 'somevalue',
    'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.City': 'somevalue',
    'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.StateOrProvinceCode': 'somevalue',
    'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.PostalCode': 'somevalue',
    'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.CountryCode': 'somevalue',
    'InboundShipmentHeader.DestinationFulfillmentCenterId': 'somevalue',
    'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipmentStatus': 'somevalue',
    'InboundShipmentHeader.LabelPrepPreference': 'somevalue',
}

call_amazon(somedict)
```

I want to pass something like

```
ShipmentHeader = InboundShipmentHeader()
ShipmentHeader['name'] = 'somevalue'
ShipmentHeader['address'] = address_datatype_instance
ShipmentHeader['fulfillment_center_id'] = 'somevalue'
ShipmentHeader['label_preference'] = 'somevalue'
ShipmentHeader['cases_required'] = 'somevalue'
ShipmentHeader['shipment_status'] = 'somevalue'

call_amazon(ShipmentHeader, otherparams)
```

In the background, the `call_amazon` method does:

```
ShipmentHeader.prefix = InboundShipmentHeader
```

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to remove the old prefix before adding the new one?

Comment: In the setter for the prefix I'm clearing the dictionary and replacing the value of _prefix with the new value.

Comment: But then your dictionary keys would have both the old and new prefixes prepended.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need to do this?

Comment: @interjay I see what you mean :(, I guess for now that can be ignored.

Comment: +1 to Blender's comment - I can think of several better alternatives, but as for which one is most appropriate, that would depend on the use-case.

Comment: The use-case is really specific, but I will be updating the question shortly...

Comment: @Aya question is updated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could subclass `dict` and add a method (I'm not sure what to call it, so let's say `dict`):

```
class AmazonDataType(dict):
    """
    Base for all Amazon datatypes.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._prefix = kwargs.pop('prefix', self.__class__.__name__)

        super(AmazonDataType, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.__getitem__(key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        return self.__setitem__(key, value)

    def dict(self):
        result = {}

        for key, value in self.items():
            if key.startswith('_'):
                continue

            key = self.fields.get(key, key)

            if isinstance(value, AmazonDataType):
                for skey, svalue in value.dict().items():
                    result['%s.%s' % (self._prefix, skey)] = svalue
            else:
                result['%s.%s' % (self._prefix, key)] = value

        return result
```

Now, the interface is a little more Pythonic:

```
class InboundShipmentHeader(AmazonDataType):
    fields = {
        'name': 'ShipmentName',
        'address': 'ShipFromAddress',
        'fulfillment_center_id': 'DestinationFulfillmentCenterId',
        'label_preference': 'LabelPrepPreference',
        'cases_required': 'AreCasesRequired',
        'shipment_status': 'ShipmentStatus',
    }

class Address(AmazonDataType):
    fields = {
        'name': 'Name',
        'address': 'AddressLine1',
        'city': 'City'
    }

address = Address(prefix='ShipFromAddress')
address.name = 'Foo'

header = InboundShipmentHeader()
header.name = 'somevalue'
header.address = address
header.fulfillment_center_id = 'somevalue'
header.label_preference = 'somevalue'
header.cases_required = 'somevalue'
header.shipment_status = 'somevalue'
```

The output of `header.dict()` is:

```
{'InboundShipmentHeader.AreCasesRequired': 'somevalue',
 'InboundShipmentHeader.DestinationFulfillmentCenterId': 'somevalue',
 'InboundShipmentHeader.LabelPrepPreference': 'somevalue',
 'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.Name': 'Foo',
 'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipmentName': 'somevalue',
 'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipmentStatus': 'somevalue'}
```

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of it, the translation you require in your abstraction class is a little more complicated that just prefixing dictionary keys.

I'd probably encapsulate the translation logic in a base class, and create subclasses for each type, with something like this...

```
class AmazonDict(dict):
    translation_dict = {}

    def __init__(self, prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix

    def translate(self):
        result = {}
        for k, v in self.iteritems():
            if k not in self.translation_dict:
                continue
            if isinstance(v, AmazonDict):
                for sk, sv in v.translate().iteritems():
                    sk = '%s.%s' % (self.prefix, sk)
                    result[sk] = sv
            else:
                k = '%s.%s' % (self.prefix, self.translation_dict[k])
                result[k] = v
        return result


class ShipmentAddress(AmazonDict):
    translation_dict = {'name': 'Name',
                        'line1': 'AddressLine1'}


class ShipmentHeader(AmazonDict):
    translation_dict = {'name': 'ShipmentName',
                        'address': 'ShipFromAddress'}


address = ShipmentAddress('ShipFromAddress')
address['name'] = 'Fred Bloggs'
address['line1'] = '123 High Street'

header = ShipmentHeader('InboundShipmentHeader')
header['name'] = 'Something'
header['address'] = address

pprint.pprint(header.translate())
```

...which also handles the recursion for child 'objects', and outputs...

```
{'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.AddressLine1': '123 High Street',
 'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.Name': 'Fred Bloggs',
 'InboundShipmentHeader.ShipmentName': 'Something'}
```

...assuming that's the format which Amazon is expecting.