# Changing dictionary keys in class object

Tags: python, class, dictionary

Let's assume I have the following class:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

And I can convert that class to dictionary like this:

```
>>> a = Test(1,2)
>>> a.__dict__
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Now, I want to change the key of that dictionary to some other thing:

```
>>> a.__dict__
{'new_a': 1, 'new_b': 2}
```

Is there a proper way of achieving this by adding some new method in the class `Test` such that it will automatically covert them to the desired output ?

Comment: No, you must manually change the dict

Comment: Why do you need to "convert" the object to a `dict` in the first place? (Note that you aren't converting anything; you are just getting a reference to the `dict` object the class uses to store the values of instance attributes.)

Comment: You can certainly alter `self.__dict__` in an instance method - is that what you mean? However, this is unlikely to be the *"proper way"* of doing whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @chepner To convert them to json with sensible keys.

Comment: Maybe look into [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761873/most-efficient-way-to-add-prefix-to-python-dictionary-keys).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `__dict__` is the wrong approach, as `__dict__` should not be modified if you do not want to change the underlying class. Add a method or property instead:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def json_dict(self):
        return dict(('new_' + name, value) for name, value in self.__dict__.items() if name != 'json_dict')

Test(1, 2).json_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Keys cannot be modified in a dictionary. What you should do is create a new dict (rather than modifying it in-place):

```
a = Test(1,2)
a.__dict__ = {afunc(k): v for (k, v) in a.__dict__}
```

If you want to change certain properties without iteration, you should:

```
a.__dict__['new_a'] = a.__dict__.pop('a')
```

**disclaimer**: I can't figure why should you need to alter the `__dict__` in an instance - it does not seem to sound so pythonic.