# Getting a sublist of a Python list, with the given indices?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a Python list, say `a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`. I also have a list of indices, say `b = [0,2,4,5]`. How can I get the list of elements of `a` with indices in `b`?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use *list comprehension* to get that list:

```
c = [a[index] for index in b]
print c
```

This is equivalent to:

```
c= []
for index in b:
    c.append(a[index])
print c
```

**Output:**

```
[0,2,4,5]
```

**Note:**

Remember that `some_list[index]` is the notation used to access to an element of a `list` in  a specific index.

Answer (score 34):

Something different...

```
>>> a = range(7)
>>> b = [0,2,4,5]
>>> import operator
>>> operator.itemgetter(*b)(a)
(0, 2, 4, 5)
```

The [`itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function takes one or more keys as arguments, and returns a function which will return the items at the given keys in *its* argument. So in the above, we create a function which will return the items at index 0, index 2, index 4, and index 5, then apply that function to `a`.

It appears to be quite a bit faster than the equivalent list comprehension

```
In [1]: import operator

In [2]: a = range(7)

In [3]: b = [0,2,4,5]

In [4]: %timeit operator.itemgetter(*b)(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 388 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit [ a[i] for i in b ]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 415 ns per loop

In [6]: f = operator.itemgetter(*b)

In [7]: %timeit f(a)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 183 ns per loop
```

---

As for why `itemgetter` is faster, the comprehension has to execute extra Python byte codes.

```
In [3]: def f(a,b): return [a[i] for i in b]

In [4]: def g(a,b): return operator.itemgetter(*b)(a)

In [5]: dis.dis(f)
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                16 (to 26)
             10 STORE_FAST               2 (i)
             13 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             16 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             19 BINARY_SUBSCR
             20 LIST_APPEND              2
             23 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   26 RETURN_VALUE
```

While `itemgetter` is a single call implemented in C:

```
In [6]: dis.dis(g)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (operator)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (itemgetter)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION_VAR        0
             12 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Likely the fastest solution, too.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. It does appear to be quite a bit faster; I'll post the test I did in `ipython`.

Comment: It's also fairly generic in the sense that it could be used to extract a sequence of values from a dictionary given the keys (which is what I've done most often with it).

Comment: Slices, even: `itemgetter(slice(2,5))(a)` -> `[2, 3, 4]`. I've added a link to the (2.x) documentation for the function.

Comment: *Why* is this faster than the more pythonic (IMHO) list comprehension?

Comment: The list comprehension has more overhead, as the iteration is set up and executed in Python. `operator.itemgetter` does its work in C.

Comment: This looks like a nice solution, but unfortunately (due to an inconsistency in `itemgetter`) breaks if the indexing list (here `b`) contains a single element.

Comment: It's not really an inconsistency with `itemgetter`; it's perfectly consistent with how `__getitem__` typically works with `slice` objects. The real problem is expecting a sequence-based solution to work with a "scalar" index. Use `itemgetter(*[b])` if `b` is a single item: convert the single item to a singleton sequence first.

Answer (score 10):

If you are a fan of [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), you could use [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) and [`list.__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> b = [0,2,4,5]
>>> map(a.__getitem__, b)
[0, 2, 4, 5]
>>>
```

The list comprehension approach is more canonical in Python though...

Answer (score 5):

Many of the proposed solutions will produce a `KeyError` if `b` contains an index not present in `a`. The following will skip invalid indices if that is desired.

```
>>> b = [0,2,4,5]
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> [x for i,x in enumerate(a) if i in b]
[0, 2, 4, 5]
>>> b = [0,2,4,500]
>>> [x for i,x in enumerate(a) if i in b]
[0, 2, 4]
```

`enumerate` produces tuples of index,value pairs. Since we have both the item and its index, we can check for the presence of the index in b

Answer (score 4):

Using [List Comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python) ,this should work -

```
li = [a[i] for i in b]
```

Testing this -

```
>>> a = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60]
>>> b = [0,2,4,5]
>>> li = [a[i] for i in b]
>>> li
[0, 20, 40, 50]
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit of speed comparison for all mentioned methods and others from [Python dictionary: Get list of values for list of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34452268/618045):

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 19 2016, 12:08:31) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

In[2]: import numpy.random as nprnd
idx = nprnd.randint(1000, size=10000)
l = nprnd.rand(1000).tolist()
from operator import itemgetter
import operator
f = operator.itemgetter(*idx)
%timeit f(l)
%timeit list(itemgetter(*idx)(l))
%timeit [l[_] for _ in idx]  # list comprehension
%timeit map(l.__getitem__, idx)
%timeit list(l[_] for _ in idx)  # a generator expression passed to a list constructor.
%timeit map(lambda _: l[_], idx)  # using 'map'
%timeit [x for i, x in enumerate(l) if i in idx]
%timeit filter(lambda x: l.index(x) in idx, l)  # UPDATE @Kundor: work only for list with unique elements
10000 loops, best of 3: 175 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 707 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 978 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 12.3 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 21.2 ms per loop
```

So the fastest is `f = operator.itemgetter(*idx); f(l)`

Comment: The filter line doesn't do the right thing. E.g. if `l` is `[1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2]`, and `idx` is `[0,1,4,5]`, then the filter method will give you `[1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2]` while all the other methods will give (correctly) `[1,2,1,2]`. Also, for consistency, you should wrap the `map` calls in `list()`.

Comment: @kundor Yes, regarding `filter` you are right in case of not unique values in list.

Comment: @Kundor, as for wrapping in `list` - it is not necessary due to this is Python 2.7.

Comment: Then why wrap `filter` in `list`?

Answer (score 4):

Using `numpy.asarray`. Numpy allows getting subarray of array by list of indices.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60]
>>> b = [0,2,4,5]
>>> res = np.asarray(a)[b].tolist()
>>> res
[0, 20, 40, 50]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative for better performance if that is important to you- it is by no means the most Pythonic but I am pretty sure it is the most efficient:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: a.index(x) in b, a))
[0, 2, 4, 5]
```

**Note:** You do not need to convert to a `list` in Python 2. However you do in Python 3 onwards (if any future visitors may have a similar issue).

Comment: Since the OP is using Python 2.7, you do not need to place `filter` in `list`.  That is only in Python 3.x.

Comment: @iCodez Thank you, I have extended my answer. I converted it to a `list` to test my solution (I am using Python 3)- however I figured I would leave my solution as that as it will not cause an error in Python 2, whilst being applicable to a wider Python 3 audience.