# How to access non-consecutive slices of a list in Python

Tags: python, indexing, slice

This is a rather basic question as I am new to Python coming from R.

In R we can access non consecutive slices in a vector or list like this:

```
> a = 1:10
> a[c(2:4, 7:9)]
[1] 2 3 4 7 8 9
> list_a = list(1:10)
> list_a[[1]][c(2:4, 7:9)]
[1] 2 3 4 7 8 9
```

I am trying to find out how to do the same with a list in Python.

E.g.

```
a = list(range(20))
a[1:4]
# returns
[1, 2, 3]
# but the following syntax creates an exception:
a[1:4, 7:9]
```

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: some suggestions will be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412509/getting-a-sublist-of-a-python-list-with-the-given-indices , I particularly like the use of operator.itemgetter  which seems to be the most efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish what you want in `a[1:4,7:9]` by using `a[1:4]+a[7:9]`.