# Python pass array into function and use it in json return

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following python code:

```py
import requests

def requestAPI(url):
  return requests.get(url=url).json()

UselessFact = RequestApi("https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en")['text']
```

I wanted to put a try/except on the `requestAPI` function so it does'nt break the code. I thought about this:

```py
import requests

def requestAPI(url, keys):
  return requests.get(url=url).json() #Here is the struggle with passing the "keys" parameter into the return

UselessFact = RequestApi("https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en", ['text'])
```

I could do something like:

```py
import requests

def requestAPI(url):
  try:
    return requests.get(url=url).json() 

  except:
    return False

UselessFact = RequestApi("https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en")['text'] if (condition here) else False
```

But i think there's a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it without a `try-except` via `dict.get()`:

```
def requestAPI(url, key):
    return requests.get(url=url).json().get(key, None)
```

This will return the value for key `key` if it exists in the JSON otherwise it will return `None`. If you want it to return `False`, do `.get(key, False)`.

Comment: I knew it could be better! Thank you!

Comment: How could i do it with multiple keys? (An array of them)

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58000060/4806357) answer, or the other ones.