# Mapping dictionary value to list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given the following dictionary:

```
dct = {'a':3, 'b':3,'c':5,'d':3}
```

How can I apply these values to a list such as:

```
lst = ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'd']
```

in order to get something like:

```
lstval = [5, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: What happens if the value in the list is not present in the dictionary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary: Get list of values for list of keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453566/python-dictionary-get-list-of-values-for-list-of-keys)

Comment: In case you are wondering about the reason behind all these unexplained downvotes, your question was linked from meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308731/failing-first-post-review-trivial-question-with-no-research-had-15

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [dct[k] for k in lst]
[5, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> [*map(dct.get, lst)]
[5, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: This seems like the best one using map, you don't need lambda for this.

Comment: It's worth noting that in python 3.x you need to type `list(map(dct.get, lst))` to get actual results back, otherwise you'll get an iterator object.

Answer (score 19):

You can use a list comprehension for this:

```
lstval = [ dct.get(k, your_fav_default) for k in lst ]
```

I personally propose using list comprehensions over built-in `map` because it looks familiar to all Python programmers, is easier to parse and extend in case a custom default value is required.

Comment: [Why use list-comp over `map`?](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) *Particularly tricky is map() invoked for the side effects of the function; the correct transformation is to use a regular for loop (since creating a list would just be wasteful).* :)

Comment: @Oleg: That's why I have `dct.get(k, your_fav_default)` in place. If values are missing it should give back the `your_fav_default`

Answer (score 15):

You can iterate keys from your list using `map` function:

```
lstval = list(map(dct.get, lst))
```

Or if you prefer list comprehension:

```
lstval = [dct[key] for key in lst]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
lstval = [d[x] for x in lst]
```

Don't name your dictionary `dict`. `dict` is the name of the type.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use a `dict` as variable name, as it was built in.

```
>>> d = {'a':3, 'b':3,'c':5,'d':3}
>>> lst = ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'd']
>>> map(lambda x:d.get(x, None), lst)
[5, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a list comprehension:

```
listval = [dict.get(key, 0) for key in lst]
```

The `.get(key, 0)` part is used to return a default value (in this case 0) if no element with this key exists in `dict`.

Comment: @Oleg The code is iterating over elements of `lst` not keys in the dictionary. So there could be something in `lst` and no corresponding key in the dict (even when this wouldn't make much sense) and we need to handle that case.

Comment: Use  listval = [dic_rev.get(key, key) for key in y]  to return original values that do not appear as keys in the dictionary you want to use

Answer (score 2):

In documentation of Python 3:

- `dict.items()` "Return a new view of the dictionary’s items ((key, value)
  pairs)" https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items
- "`zip()` in conjunction with the * operator can be used to unzip a
  list" https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

So, `zip(*d.items())` give your result.

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

print(d.items())        # [('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('d', 4)] in Python 2
                        # dict_items([('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('d', 4)]) in Python 3

print(zip(*d.items()))  # [('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('d', 4)] in Python 2
                        # <zip object at 0x7f1f8713ed40> in Python 3

k, v = zip(*d.items())
print(k)                # ('a', 'c', 'b', 'd')
print(v)                # (1, 3, 2, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Mapping dictionary values to a nested list**

The question has already been answered by many. However, no one has mentioned a solution in case the list is nested.

By changing the list in the original question to a list of lists

```
dct = {'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 5, 'd': 3}    

lst = [['c', 'd'], ['a'], ['b', 'd']]
```

The mapping can be done by a nested list comprehension

```
lstval = [[dct[e] for e in lst[idx]] for idx in range(len(lst))]

# lstval = [[5, 3], [3], [3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Anand S Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/795990/anand-s-kumar) rightfully pointed out that you **run into problems when a value in your list is not available in the dictionary**.

One more robust solution is to **add an if/else condition to your list comprehension**. By that you make sure the code doesn't break.

By that you **only change the values in the list where you have a corresponding key in the dictionary** and **otherwise keep the original value**.

```
m = {'a':3, 'b':3, 'c':5, 'd':3}
l = ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'other_value']
l_updated = [m[x] if x in m else x for x in l]
```

[OUT]

```
[5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 'other_value']
```