# Pandas replace values with dictionary values using python built in map() function

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this `{'Note1':'Desc1','Note2':'Desc2','Note3':'Desc3'}`
and a dataframe with values like this:

```
{0: 'Note1',
 1: 'Note1',
 2: 'Note1',
 3: 'Note2',
 4: 'Note2',
 5: 'Note2;Note3',
 6: 'Note2;Note3',
 7: 'Note3',
```

I want to have a new column where the description is mapped to the note number, so I do this:

```
df['noteText'] = df['NoteRef'].map(notelist)
```

This works great, except that the double values return NaN.
So I made this:

```
def swap(x):
    x = x.split(';')
    for y in x:
        y = map(notelist, y)

swap(df['NoteRef'].iloc[-2]) # just to test
df['noteText'] = df['NoteRef'].apply(swap)
```

But I don't really know how map() in python would work here (doesn't work like in pandas). When I print `y` I get a map object, when I print `list(y)` I get `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`.

So I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction, as this seems like something easy. If there is a better way to do this, I would greatly appreciate learning it.
Thank you.

Comment: What is expected description in case of multiple values? Description of first Note? The last one? Concatenation?

Comment: Description of both in order, like 'Desc2,Desc3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078554/mapping-dictionary-value-to-list) post.

```
def swap(x):
    x = x.split(';')
    x = [*map(notelist.get, x)]
    x = ",".join(x)
    return x
df['noteText'] = df['NoteRef'].apply(swap)
```