# Python: efficient way to create a list from dict values with a given order

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like:

```py
myDict = { "age":value1,"size":value2,'weigth':value3 ... }
```

And I simply want to get a list of values from this dictionary BUT in some order defined by a list:

```py
order_list = ["age","weigth","size", ... ]
```

So the result will be:

```py
result_list = [value1,value3,value2, ... ]
```

The simplest way is to iterate through the `order_list` this way:

```py
for key in order_list:
    result_list.append(myDict[key])
```

But I beleive that there is a more efficient and clean way to do what I am trying to do as this method is expensive for two reasons:

1. The column list is very long
2. I need to do this 1000 time / second

Comment: Related thread with a benchmark: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453566/python-dictionary-get-list-of-values-for-list-of-keys.

Comment: I don't think so, dictionaries are hash tables, so retrieval is O(1) and total complexity is O(n), which is optimal. So you should probably try something completely different

Comment: Nah, as @BlackBear points out, you won't get better than `O(n)`. A little comprehension could be considered cleaner, but won't improve performance.

Comment: I added an additional answer to the "duplicate"

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension is shorter:

```
myDict = { "age":"value1","size":"value2",'weigth':"value3"}
order_list = ["age","weigth","size"]
result_list = [myDict[x] for x in order_list]
```

`map` will do as well:

```
# Python 3.x (map returns an iterator)
result_list = list(map(myDict.get, order_list))

# Python 2.x (map returns a list)
result_list = map(myDict.get, order_list)
```