# Is there a way to get values using one of the keys in O(1) time

Tags: python, dictionary, data-modeling

I am modeling data for an application and decided to choose dictionary as my data structure. But each row in the data has multiple keys. So I created a dictionary with multiple keys mapping each row, something like:

```
>>> multiKeyDict = {}
>>> multiKeyDict[('key1','key2','key3')] = 'value1'
>>> multiKeyDict.get(('key1','key2','key3'))
'value1'
```

Now I have to retrieve all the values with `key1` in O(1) time. From my research I know I could do:

- use [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multi_key_dict) package to get the job done but not sure if it is O(1)
- search for keys as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453567/4085019

I am also open for any better data structures instead of using the dictionary.

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: The package you mention maps a list of keys to the same value. If I understand your question correctly, you want more some kind of hierarchy?

Comment: why not make 2 dictionaries? 1 like `{'key1':['value1','value2']}`  and one like `{'value1':['key1', 'key2']}`

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters.

Comment: @Chris_Rands because value is a comma delimited long string

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, I was wondering if some tree structure might fit in

Comment: @PseudoAj: so? That's still one object.

Comment: @PseudoAj So? Strings are hashable and can be keys?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I feel it's a hacky solution but definitely would give it a try

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, it is hashable ad can be done but feels hacky solution.

Comment: @PseudoAj Why is it hacky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have multiple keys. As far as the Python dictionary is concerned, there is just **one** key, a tuple object. You can't search for the constituents of the tuple in anything other than O(N) linear time.

If your keys are unique, just add each key individually:

```
multiKeyDict['key1'] = multiKeyDict['key2'] = multiKeyDict['key3'] = 'value1'
```

Now you have 3 keys all referencing one value. The value object is not duplicated here, only the references to it are.

The `multi_key_dict` package you found uses an intermediate mapping to map a given constituent key to the composite key, which then maps to the value. This gives you O(1) search too, with the same limitation that each constituent key must be unique.

If your keys are *not* unique then you need to map each key to another container that then holds the values, like a set for instance:

```
for key in ('key1', 'key2', 'key3):
    multiKeyDict.setdefault(key, set()).add(value)
```

Now looking up a key gives you the set of all values that that key references.

If you need to be able to combine keys too, then you can add additional references with those combinations. Key-value pairings are relatively cheap, it's all just references. The key and value objects themselves are not duplicated.

Comment: `key1` might have multiple values and I don't want to map values to each keys as it won't scale with data

Comment: @PseudoAj: then you don't have data that is suitable for a hash table, and are stuck with a linear search for this data structure. The same applies to the `multi_key_dict` package you found.

Comment: @PseudoAj what do you mean by "won't scale with data"

Comment: @PseudoAj: so what did you expect to find when searching for `key1` if there are multiple values? You can't have a O(1) search if there are K values per key.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre for each row you are creating three entries in the data. So if you have million records then you will be having 3 million records ... also think about if I want to add additional key..

Comment: @PseudoAj at least it doesn't copy the values. Only dict entries.

Comment: @PseudoAj: if you have millions of records with complex relationships, then it sounds like you want a relational database instead. Let *it* worry about efficient data structures.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I am now seriously thinking of using database or key value store like Redis for this...

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to build up an index to a list of row-objects which share a key-component. Provided the number of rows sharing any particular key value is small, this will be quite efficient. (Assume row-objects have keys accessed as `row.key1`, `row.key2` etc., that's not a very relevant detail). Untested code:

```
index = {}
for row in rows:
    index.setdefault( row.key1, []).append(row)
    index.setdefault( row.key2, []).append(row)
    index.setdefault( row.key3, []).append(row)
```

and then for looking up rows that match, say, `key2` and `key3`

```
candidates = index[ key2] 
if len( index[key3]) < len(candidates): 
    candidates = index[key3] # use key3 if it offers a better distribution
results = []
for cand in candidates:
    if cand.key2 == key2 and cand.key3 == key3: # full test is necessary!
        results.append( cand)
```