# want to find a matching variable from multi key possibly tuples in dict and print the value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

How can i  search a variable from a multi key dict and get the respective value in python?

```
dict1 = {('1700','2700','3700'):'a3g3',('1502','1518'):'a2g3',('2600'):'a3g2'}

var = '1502'
```

**output**

> should be **a2g3**

Comment: A dictionary is designed for lookups by the *full* key. Any other lookup is going to be inefficient. If the actual size of the dictionary is large and there are multiple lookups it might be a good idea to reshape the data structure to allow efficient lookups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary: Get list of values for list of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453566/python-dictionary-get-list-of-values-for-list-of-keys)

Comment: Whether there's a solution or not, the tuple/list used as key doesn't ensure the unicity of the keys/sub-keys. Using such a thing likely will produce a disaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
dict1 = {('1700','2700','3700'): 'a3g3',
         ('1502','1518'): 'a2g3',
         ('2600'): 'a3g2'}

print(next(v for k, v in dict1.items() if '1502' in k))
# a2g3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the keys and find

```
   print([dict1[i] for i in dict1.keys() if var in i])
```

Comment: Code only answer is not helpful

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this snippet just degrades the dict (hashmap) lookup time complexity from O(1) to O(n) and will return a list of a single value or empty list.
It seems to be just replicating `dict1.get(var)` wrapped in a list.

Comment: @GergelyM It will return a list of tuples.

Comment: It returns a string as a single item list - but iterates the whole Dictionary even if it found one -> so it's a certain O(n) lookup.
This solution would return multiple items if the key is repeated in the non-unique keys  -> `('1700','1502','3700')` or `('1502','1518')` or `('1502')` are perfectly valid and unique keys, although each has the value of `var`, thus the snippet will return 3 values as a list... Otherwise, I'd prefer your answer as the solution above the others.

Comment: It will return as you said only

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is good approach ,

Here is Filter approach just for fun :
You can filter the result :

```
dict1 = {('1700','2700','3700'):'a3g3',('1502','1518'):'a2g3',('2600'):'a3g2'}

var = '1502'
print(dict1[list(filter(lambda x:var in x,dict1.keys()))[0]])
```

output:

```
a2g3
```