# How to extract dictionary values by using multiple keys at the same time?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have got the below problem.

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Normal retrieval method: `dict1['a']`  -> Output - > `1`
expected method: `dict1['a', 'b']` - > Output - > `[1, 2]`

My requirement is to extract multiple values from a dictionary by providing multiple keys at the same time as mentioned in the expected method above.

Is there a  way to do it? If I have to edit the built-in dict class methods, how do I do it?

Comment: why not just `[dict1['a'], dict1['b']]`?

Comment: could use `[dict1[key] for key in ["a", "b"]]`

Comment: What you want can be achieved in several ways as the comments and answers show. You should not be considering subclassing `dict` purely to achieve a syntactic convenience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary: Get list of values for list of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453566/python-dictionary-get-list-of-values-for-list-of-keys)

Comment: my requirement is to achieve the below scenario   dict1['a', 'b'] - > Output - > [1, 2]

Answer (score 7):

You can do what's said in the other answers or use `map` on your list of keys with the `get` dictionary method:

```py
list(map(dict1.get, ["a", "b"]))
```

Comment: This answer return 'map object'. Must be enclose with 'list' for result to be 'list' 
==> 
list(map(dict1.get, ["a", "b"]))

Comment: @ErmanKadirKahraman If the need is just to iterate over it, keeping it as a map is good enough and even a better practice.
I'd advice to convert to a list only if you specifically need a list

Answer (score 4):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[ dict[k] for k in ('a','b')]
[ dict[k] for k in my_iterable ]
```

will throw KeyError if any of the keys in the iterable are not in the dict. It may be better to do

```
[ dict.get(k, my_default_value) for k in my_iterable ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension : `[dict1[key] for key in ('a', 'b')]`

It is equivalent to

```py
output = []
for key in ('a', 'b'):
    output.append(dict1[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing this through subclassing:

```
class CustomDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, dic):
        self.dic = dic

    def __getitem__(self, items):
        values = []
        for item in items:
            values.append(self.dic[item])
        return values if len(values) > 1 else values[0]


d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

new_d = CustomDict(d)

print(new_d['a'])
print(new_d['a', 'b'])
print(new_d['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(new_d['a', 'c', 'd'])
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 1
> [1, 2]
> [1, 2, 3]
> [1, 3, 4]
> ```

Explanation:

The `new_d` is an object of the `CustomDict` class, it will always fall back to the parent class's methods (so that looping over the object and other things you might want to do to a dictionary work) except when one of the overriden methods (init, getitem) get called.

So when one uses `new_d['a', 'b']` the overriden `__getitem__` method gets called. The overriden method uses the `__getitem__` of the `self.dic` (which is a normal dictionary) to actually access the dictionary values for every key given.