# I'm trying to extract the values of a dictionary based on a list containing all of its keys, but I get "unhashable type: 'list'" errors

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

Based on the list comprehension solution of [Python dictionary: Get list of values for list of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453566/python-dictionary-get-list-of-values-for-list-of-keys?newreg=baa855ab392a4b35a8ddbc2f61109370) question, I'm trying to do the same for my dict "values-extraction" but I get either `'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed` error or `unhashable type: 'list'` :( please help.

I have a dict :

```
region_colors = {
 'Speyside': '#0173b2',
 'Highlands': '#de8f05',
 'Lowlands': '#029e73',
 'Islands': '#d55e00',
 'Campbelltown': '#cc78bc',
 'Islay': '#ca9161'}
```

and a list:

```
region_colsbis = [[
  'Highlands',
  'Speyside',
  'Speyside',
  'Speyside',
  'Speyside',
  'Lowlands',
  'Speyside',
  'Speyside',
  'Islay',
  'Highlands',
  ...,
  'Highlands']]
```

which actually comes from an extraction of a dataframe column.

I need to convert this past list into the value elements of the dict `region_colors`, so that every time the `region_colsbis` list says `'Highlands'` a new list (say `region_cols`) reflects `'#de8f05'`

expected output:

```
region_cols = ['#de8f05', '#0173b2', '#0173b2', '#0173b2', '#0173b2', '#029e73', ...]
```

I've tried doing

```
[region_colors[x] for x in region_colsbis]
```

and

```
for element in region_colsbis:
    region_cols.append(region_colors[element].value)
```

but I keep getting the errors mentioned before. Could you demigods of Python please help this humble peasant?

Comment: The problem is that your list of `region_colsbis` is nested because you have double-[ there. Just use a single [ and it should be fine.

Comment: This is totally off-topic, but I have a grammar note: A semicolon (`;`) is used to join two *independent* clauses together, but a clause starting with "but" or "so that" is *dependent*. I fixed them for you.

Comment: How are you extracting `region_colsbis` from the df column? That seems to be where the problem is. BTW, you might want to read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Guys, I didnt know about the issues a nested list could bring and I actually hadnt notice it, thanks for all the help, the solution you proposed works perfectly and I will be more careful next time I work with DF. Awesome welcoming for me to Stackoverflow world, thanks! Ill see you next time

Answer (score 0):

`region_colsbis` is a *nested* list. So in this case, you can select the first sublist, `region_colsbis[0]`.

```
[region_colors[x] for x in region_colsbis[0]]
```

However, this may fail if it's not guaranteed that `len(region_colsbis) == 1`, and you haven't said how you're extracting it from the dataframe column, so I don't know.

There might actually be a better way to do it, like [`Series.map(region_colors)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'regions': [
        'Highlands',
        'Speyside',
        'Speyside',
        'Speyside',
        'Speyside',
        'Lowlands',
        'Speyside',
        'Speyside',
        'Islay',
        'Highlands',
        'Highlands']
    })

df['regions'].map(region_colors).rename('region_cols')
```

Output:

```
0     #de8f05
1     #0173b2
2     #0173b2
3     #0173b2
4     #0173b2
5     #029e73
6     #0173b2
7     #0173b2
8     #ca9161
9     #de8f05
10    #de8f05
Name: region_cols, dtype: object
```

Comment: So I extracted the list from the DF using this:  region_colsbis=[(whisky['Region']).astype(str).values.tolist()] as otherwise I would´ve ended with a Series like object, something like [0, 'Highlands'\n, ...] and probably thats why I ended with a nested list, the len of region_colsbis is indeed ==1 as you just predicted and the solution you gave works perfect, Thank you very much! and thanks for the grammar tip and the welcoming too! Have an amazing day!