# Subclassing dict causes error TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, typeerror

I'm trying to subclass `dict` but I get the error in the subject when trying to override the `__getitem__` function. I obtained the initial implementation of the derived class [from this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict-and-override-get-set)

The idea is to check if a key exists (a key is a tuple of 2 strings), and if not add the key to the dictionary and return its value. The values of the dictionary are obtained by calling `eval()` on the concatenated strings of the key. By the way, I know of the existence of default dictionaries (which may help in this case), but I wanted to do it differently. This is the code

```
class DictSubclass(dict):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.update(*args, **kwargs)

  def __getitem__(self, key):

    if not key in dict:

      fn = '{}_{}'.format(key[0], key[1])
      dict.__setitem__(key,eval(fn))

    val = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
    return val

  def __setitem__(self, key, val):
    dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)

  def __repr__(self):
    dictrepr = dict.__repr__(self)
    return '%s(%s)' % (type(self).__name__, dictrepr)

  def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for k, v in dict(*args, **kwargs).items():
        self[k] = v
```

Why am I getting the following error?

```
line 21, in __getitem__
    if not key in dict:
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable
```

Comment: The `dict` in `if not key in dict` is the `dict` type. You probably meant to write `if not key in self`.

Answer (score 4):

You should have used `if not key in self:`. As `if not key in dict:` asks if the `key` is in the class `dict` which as classes are not iterables, fails.

Comment: Thanks! that was the issue.