# Is there a way to associate a callback to the change of a list?

Tags: python, events, observable, watch

In jQuery, for example, you can do

```js
$(input).on("change", callback);
```

Is there a way to do something similar in Python with, for example, a list? Something like this (pseudo-code):

```py
from watch import Watchman

enemies = ["Moloch", "Twilight Lady", "Big Figure", "Captain Carnage", "Nixon"]

owl = Watchman()

def enemies_changed(old, new):
    print(f"Enemies was {old}, now are {new}")

owl.watch(enemies, enemies_changed)

enemies.append("Alien")

# Enemies was ['Moloch', 'Twilight Lady', 'Big Figure', 'Captain Carnage', 'Nixon'], now are ['Moloch', 'Twilight Lady', 'Big Figure', 'Captain Carnage', 'Nixon', 'Alien']
```

Comment: The top answer to this question might help you: [How to detect if any element in a dictionary changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26189090/5431791)

Comment: Which package is giving you the `watch` import?

Comment: @James It's a "fictional" example :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Method 1: creating your own class

You can implement this with a generator and by subclassing `list`.  You will have to override every method you want to watch.  Here is a simple example.

```py
def watcher(name=''):
    while True:
        x = yield
        msg = f'{name} was {x}'
        y = yield
        if y is not None:
            msg += f', now is {y}'
            print(msg)
    
class List(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, gen=None, **kwargs):
        self.__gen = gen
        next(gen)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def __add__(self, other):
        try:
            self.__gen.send(self)
            super().__add__(other)
            self.__gen.send(self)
        except:
            next(self.__gen)
            raise
        
    def __setitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.__gen.send(self)
            super().__setitem__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.__gen.send(self)
        except:
            next(self.__gen)
            raise
        
    def append(self, value):
        self.__gen.send(self)
        super().append(value)
        self.__gen.send(self)
```

Examples:

```py
owl = watcher('Enemies')
enemies = List(["Moloch", "Twilight Lady", "Big Figure", "Captain Carnage", "Nixon"], gen=owl)

enemies.append('Alien')
# prints:
Enemies was ['Moloch', 'Twilight Lady', 'Big Figure', 'Captain Carnage', 'Nixon'], now is ['Moloch', 'Twilight Lady', 'Big Figure', 'Captain Carnage', 'Nixon', 'Alien']

enemies[-1] = 'Aliens'
# prints:
Enemies was ['Moloch', 'Twilight Lady', 'Big Figure', 'Captain Carnage', 'Nixon', 'Alien'], now is ['Moloch', 'Twilight Lady', 'Big Figure', 'Captain Carnage', 'Nixon', 'Aliens']
```

## Method 2: Monkey-patching `list`

Here is an example that monkey-patches the `list` built-in type to add wrapped methods.  In this case we are just adding capitalized versions of the methods that mutate the list; i.e. `.append` becomes .Append`.

Code for monkey-patching is from https://gist.github.com/bricef/1b0389ee89bd5b55113c7f3f3d6394ae.  You can just copy this to a file called `patch.py` and use `from patch import monkey_patch_list`

```py
import ctypes
from types import MappingProxyType, MethodType


# figure out side of _Py_ssize_t
if hasattr(ctypes.pythonapi, 'Py_InitModule4_64'):
    _Py_ssize_t = ctypes.c_int64
else:
    _Py_ssize_t = ctypes.c_int


# regular python
class _PyObject(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

_PyObject._fields_ = [
    ('ob_refcnt', _Py_ssize_t),
    ('ob_type', ctypes.POINTER(_PyObject))
]


# python with trace
if object.__basicsize__ != ctypes.sizeof(_PyObject):
    class _PyObject(ctypes.Structure):
        pass
    _PyObject._fields_ = [
        ('_ob_next', ctypes.POINTER(_PyObject)),
        ('_ob_prev', ctypes.POINTER(_PyObject)),
        ('ob_refcnt', _Py_ssize_t),
        ('ob_type', ctypes.POINTER(_PyObject))
    ]


class _DictProxy(_PyObject):
    _fields_ = [('dict', ctypes.POINTER(_PyObject))]


def reveal_dict(proxy):
    if not isinstance(proxy, MappingProxyType):
        raise TypeError('dictproxy expected')
    dp = _DictProxy.from_address(id(proxy))
    ns = {}
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyDict_SetItem(ctypes.py_object(ns),
                                    ctypes.py_object(None),
                                    dp.dict)
    return ns[None]


def get_class_dict(cls):
    d = getattr(cls, '__dict__', None)
    if d is None:
        raise TypeError('given class does not have a dictionary')
    if isinstance(d, MappingProxyType):
        return reveal_dict(d)
    return d


class Listener:
    def __init__(self):
        self._g = None
    def __call__(self, x=None):
        if x is None:
            return self._g
        self._g = x
    def send(self, val):
        if self._g:
            self._g.send(val)


def monkey_patch_list(decorator, mutators=None):
    if not mutators:
        mutators = (
            'append', 'clear', 'extend', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 
            'reverse', 'sort'
        )
    d_list = get_class_dict(list)
    d_list['_listener'] = Listener()
    for m in mutators:
        d_list[m.capitalize()] = decorator(d_list.get(m))
```

Now we can basically use what we had above, which is defining a decorator that wraps the list methods and yeilds the list's `str` representation before mutation and again after mutation.  You can then pass any function that accepts two arguments and a `name` keyword argument to handle the alerting.

```py
def before_after(clsm):
    '''decorator for list class methods'''
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._listener.send(self)
        out = clsm(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._listener.send(self)
        return out
    return wrapper


class Watchman:
    def __init__(self):
        self.guarding = []

    def watch(self, lst, fn, name='list'):
        self.guarding.append((lst, name))
        w = self._watcher(fn, name)
        lst._listener(w)
            
    @staticmethod
    def _watcher(fn, name):
        def gen():
            while True:
                x = yield
                x = str(x)
                y = yield
                y = str(y)
                print(fn(x, y, name=name))
        g = gen()
        next(g)
        return g
```

Now you can patch and use the new methods with the standard list constructor.

```py
def enemies_changed(old, new, name='list'):
    print(f"{name} was {old}, now are {new}")


# update the list methods with the wrapper
monkey_patch_list(before_after)

enemies = ["Moloch", "Twilight Lady", "Big Figure", "Captain Carnage", "Nixon"]
owl = Watchman()
owl.watch(enemies, enemies_changed, 'Enemies')

enemies.Append('Alien')
# prints:
Enemies was ['Moloch', 'Twilight Lady', 'Big Figure', 'Captain Carnage', 'Nixon'], 
now are ['Moloch', 'Twilight Lady', 'Big Figure', 'Captain Carnage', 'Nixon', 'Alien']
```

## Method 3: overloading the `list` built-in with your own implementation

This method is similar to method 1, but you can still use the `list` constructor as usual.  We are basically going to over-write the built-in `list` class with our own subclassed version.  The methods are the same syntax, we are just adding a listener and receiver attribute, we are also wrapping the mutating methods so that the listener picks up on them and sends a signal to the receiver is one is set.

```py
# save the built-in list
_list = list

class list(_list):
    def __init__(self, *args, emit_change=False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._emit = emit_change
        self._listener = self._make_gen() if emit_change else None
        self._init_change_emitter()
        self._receiver = None

    @property
    def emit_change(self):
        return self._emit
        
    @property
    def emitter(self):
        return self._emitter

    def _make_gen(self):
        def gen():
            while True:
                x = yield
                x = str(x)
                y = yield
                y = str(y)
                yield (x, y)
        g = gen()
        next(g)
        return g
        
    def _init_change_emitter(self):
        def before_after(clsm):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                if self._listener:
                    self._listener.send(self)
                    out = clsm(*args, **kwargs)
                    before, after = self._listener.send(self)
                    if self._receiver:
                        self._receiver.send((before, after))
                else:
                    out = clsm(*args, **kwargs)
                return out
            return wrapper
        mutators = (
            'append', 'clear', 'extend', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove',
            'reverse', 'sort'
        )
        for m_str in mutators:
            m = self.__getattribute__(m_str)
            self.__setattr__(m_str, before_after(m))
```

At this point `list` works just like before.  Using `list('abc')` returns the output `['a', 'b', 'c']`, as you would expect, and so does `list('abc', emit_change=True)`.  The additional key-word argument allows to hook in receiver that gets sent before and after snippets of the list when it mutates.

A list constructed using brackets will need to be passed through the `list` constructor to turn on listening/emitting.

Example:

```
class Watchman:
    def __init__(self):
        self.guarding = []
        
    def watch(self, lst, fn, name='list'):
        if not lst._listener:
            raise ValueError(
                'Can only watch lists initialized with `emit_change=True`.'
            )
        r = self._make_receiver(fn, name)
        lst._receiver = r
        self.guarding.append((lst, name, r))
        
    def _make_receiver(self, fn, name):
        def receiver():
            while True:
                x, y = yield
                print(fn(x, y, name=name))
        r = receiver()
        next(r)
        return r
        
def enemies_changed(old, new, name):
    return f"{name} was {old}\nNow is {new}"
        
        
enemies = ["Moloch", "Twilight Lady", "Big Figure", "Captain Carnage", "Nixon"]
enemies = list(enemies, emit_change=True)
owl = Watchman()
owl.watch(enemies, enemies_changed, 'Enemies')
enemies.append('Alien')
# prints:
Enemies was: ['Moloch', 'Twilight Lady', 'Big Figure', 'Captain Carnage', 'Nixon']
Now is: ['Moloch', 'Twilight Lady', 'Big Figure', 'Captain Carnage', 'Nixon', 'Alien']
```

Hope one of these helps!

Comment: Mh. No thanks, I prefer to not do a subclass. But thank you anyway for your answer :-)

Comment: Would you be ok with monkey-patching in new methods for the default `list` class?

Comment: Alright, I added 2 more methods, see if the #3 in particular is helpful