# Is it possible to change the value of a key in a dictionary in a similar way an excel sheet would do?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d_1 = {
    "k1":{
        "a":0.215,
        "b":350
    },
    "k2":{
        "a":1.0125,
        "b":1.1802
    }
}
```

I want to create a second dictionary that stores the result of `0.215/1.0125`, stored in the a keys of `k1` and `k2` dictionaries, but I want the value to update in the same fashion that an excel sheets does.

To illustrate this, imagine you have the cell `A1 = 0.215` and cell `B1 = 1.0125`. Then cell `C1` would be `A1/B1`. If you update `A1` or `B1`, the value of `C1` is automatically updated.

Is there any way to create a second dictionary `d_2` which key stores the result of `d_1["k1"]["a"]/d_1["k2"]["a"]` and updates the result dynamically, like the excel example? And if its not possible, what is the closest thing I could do to achieve this?

---

EDIT:

The desired solution I'm looking is something similar to having shallow copies of parts of `d_1`, like `d_1["k1"]["a"]/d_1["k2"]["a"]`. I know that if I have two dictionaries and one is the copy of the other, if I change the value of one `key-value` pair in the first dictionary, the second dictionary should also change. To get a "hard" copy of the first dictionary `deepcopy` should be used.

Can something like a shallow copy of the dictionary but applying the mathematical operation be done or its not possible?

Answer (score 0):

from my experience , it's a little bit hard to automatically update values , if you want to should set up a listener to know whether u changed the value of a in dictionary k1 or b in k2 dictionary

I might suggest you the following answers for the " how to listen on values change in a dict " [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189090/how-to-detect-if-any-element-in-a-dictionary-changes)

variables are stored in the memory so to detect the values changing you need a listener to compare the old dict and the new one

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I'm looking more for an automated update of the value rather than listening to changes in the values. I also edited the question, so please take a look :)