# How to prevent key creation through d[key] = val

Tags: python, dictionary, key, python-3.4

Suppose I have `d = {'dogs': 3}`. Using:

```
d['cats'] = 2
```

would create the key `'cats'` and give it the value `2`.

If I really intend to update a dict with a new key and value, I would use `d.update(cats=2)` because it feels more explicit.

Having automatic creation of a key feels error prone (especially in larger programs), e.g.:

```
# I decide to make a change to my dict.
d = {'puppies': 4, 'big_dogs': 2}


# Lots and lots of code.
# ....

def change_my_dogs_to_maximum_room_capacity():
    # But I forgot to change this as well and there is no error to inform me.
    # Instead a bug was created.
    d['dogs'] = 1
```

---

**Question:**
Is there a way to disable the automatic creation of a key that doesn't exist through `d[key] = value`, and instead raise a `KeyError`?

Everything else should keep working though:

```
d = new_dict()                  # Works
d = new_dict(hi=1)              # Works
d.update(c=5, x=2)              # Works
d.setdefault('9', 'something')  # Works

d['a_new_key'] = 1              # Raises KeyError
```

Comment: I guess you could subclass `dict` and write a custom function for the relevant magic method.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict-and-override-getitem-setitem

Comment: You've contradicted yourself. Why didn't you use `d.update(dogs=1)` like you said you would?

Comment: @chepner hmm i guess I wasn't clear enough.  Because that function doesn't intend to create a new key, rather change the value of the old one. But forgetting to change the function, because of the automatic insertion, would go unnoticed.

Comment: Not what you ask for, but if the key names are fixed by the program (not read from a file), consider replacing your dictionary with a custom class. The [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#slots) declaration fixes the attribute names that can be inserted into objects of this class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a child of `dict` with a special `__setitem__` method that refuses keys that didn't exist when it was initially created:

```
class StrictDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self:
            raise KeyError("{} is not a legal key of this StricDict".format(repr(key)))
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

x = StrictDict({'puppies': 4, 'big_dogs': 2})
x["puppies"] = 23 #this works
x["dogs"] = 42    #this raises an exception
```

It's not totally bulletproof (it will allow `x.update({"cats": 99})` without complaint, for example), but it prevents the most likely case.

Comment: @JoranBeasley It Shouldn't™, since it inherits, all other magic methods will stay around.

Comment: ahh it seems your right ... I swear ive done this with strings and it broke all the magic methods that I didnt explicitly subclass ... maybe its just cause string is more primitive than dict or something

Comment: This approach provided a good solution to me, which I describe here (too long for StackOverflow): https://persagen.com/2020/03/05/python_dictionaries_default_values_immutable_keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Inherit `dict` class and override `__setitem__` to suits your needs.Try this

```
class mydict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        raise KeyError(key)

>>>a=mydict({'a':3})
>>>d
{'a': 3}
>>>d['a']
3
>>>d['b']=4
KeyError: 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only allow new keys to be added with `key=value` using update:

```
 class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, d):
        dict.__init__(self)
        self.instant = False
        self.update(d)

    def update(self, other=None, **kwargs):
        if other is not None:
            if isinstance(other, dict):
                for k, v in other.items():
                    self[k] = v
            else:
                for k, v in other:
                    self[k] = v
        else:
            dict.update(self, kwargs)
        self.instant = True

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if self.instant and key not in self:
            raise KeyError(key)
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

x = MyDict({1:2,2:3})
x[1] = 100 # works
x.update(cat=1) # works
x.update({2:200}) # works 
x["bar"] = 3 # error
x.update({"foo":2}) # error
x.update([(5,2),(3,4)])  # error
```