# Access dict hierarchically

Tags: python

Want to access a `dict` via a String like `dict[accessor]` while `acccessor` is `'keyA.nestedKeyB'`. Found something here with Lambda and overwriting the `dict` class ( `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818669/dynamically-accessing-nested-dictionary-keys` ) but unfortunetly there is no working example.

### Code

```
data = { "keyA": { "nestedKeyB": "Hello" } }

print(data['keyA']['nestedKeyB'])  # prints 'Hello'

accessor = 'keyA.nestedKeyB'
print(data[accessor])  # KeyError
```

Comment: You cannot do this with a `dict`. You could write your own class that does this, but why? Why not just use the regular way? You can even very trivially use `'keyA.nestedKeyB'` to generate the keys using `'keyA.nestedKeyB'.split('.')` Note, you can't "overwrite" the dict class, and even if you could you really shouldn't

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA: My fault. Corrected it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: The dict can have different nested levels. For that reason my `accessor` could have different amount of keys. Because of that I need a way to access each level by the `accessor`. I do not understand your `split` example.

Comment: So what? Again, just *split* the accessors then loop over them and access, essentially like the answers in the question you already linked to...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: You are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since python dict doesn't support dot notations, you will have to convert the accessor to `foo["bar"]["baz"]` form.

Something as simple as,

```py
def access(foo, accessor):
    keys = accessor.split('.')
    data = foo
    for key in keys:
        data = data[key]
    return data
```

Comment: @ZhdZilin. Post answer then

Answer (score 0):

```
import jsonpath
import json #in this sample, don't need import this.
data = { "keyA": { "nestedKeyB": "Hello" } }
node = jsonpath.jsonpath(data, "$.keyA.nestedKeyB")
print(node) # if node is not False, it's a list
print (node == False) # not found match result by this jsonpath? Then node == False
```

recommend you to use jsonpath library and JSONPath expression. You can work with more complex json data