# Missing data using pandas map

Tags: python, pandas

Here is what we can read from the [pandas map function documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) :

> When arg is a dictionary, values in Series that are not in the dictionary (as keys) are converted to NaN. However, if the dictionary is a dict subclass that defines **missing** (i.e. provides a method for default values), then this default is used rather than NaN

So I tried to apply this note with this code :

```
import pandas as pd 

class Missing_dict(dict) :

  def __init__(self,*arg,**kw):
      super(Missing_dict, self).__init__(*arg, **kw)

  def __missing__(self, key) :
    return key

md = Missing_dict({"a" : 0})

df = pd.DataFrame([{"key" : "a", "value" : 0}, {"key" : "b", "value" : 1}])

print (df)
print (df["key"].map(md))
```

But the result is not what I expect, in my case I want to map the data from one column, and if a value is not found in the dictionnary, then I would like this value as result (in other words, I would like the value if the key is in the dictionary, otherwise the key).

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: try `df["key"].replace(md)`

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly ! However isn't the previous code supposed to work too ?

Comment: `map` doesn't handle missing values in the way you want, it has a `na_action` param but this will either return `NaN` or return a single scalar value, what you're wanting to do is replace if the key is found, if not keep existing value which is what `replace` does

Comment: Also are you sure you've sufficiently sub-classed the `dict` class? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict-and-override-getitem-setitem

Comment: A similar subject (and the corresponding drawback) seems to be later discussed in the post below, but I can not call it a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67826593/pandas-map-dictionary-default-missing-value