# TKinter : filter a dataframe by listbox objects

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, listbox

I'm trying to create a small application to directly download data according to several criteria via TKINTER.
I'm having trouble with one element in particular, namely the "Listbox" widget. In the example below, I've isolated the part of the code that's giving me problems.
I want to filter a column of the df downloaded by API via the items selected in my listbox. However, it always returns an empty dataframe because it can't make the link between the widget elements and the data in my dataframe.

I've tried a few differents things, but i'm stuck. i could use a little help...

Below is an example of a df with the relevant column and my code. In this example, i'm trying to select the rows with slice 01 for export.

**[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUnaT.png)**

**My code :**

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

# Fonction pour filtrer le DataFrame en fonction des tranches d'effectifs sélectionnées
def select_ets_effectifs(df, effectifs_box):
    selected_rows = df.copy()
    
    # Mapping des tranches d'effectifs vers des codes plus courts
    effectifs_mapping = {
        "00 - 0 salarié": "00",
        "01 - 1 ou 2 salariés": "01",
        "02 - 3 à 5 salariés": "02",
        "03 - 6 à 9 salariés": "03",
        "11 - 10 à 19 salariés": "11",
        "12 - 20 à 49 salariés": "12",
        "21 - 50 à 99 salariés": "21",
        "22 - 100 à 199 salariés": "22",
        "31 - 200 à 249 salariés": "31",
        "32 - 250 à 499 salariés": "32",
        "41 - 500 à 999 salariés": "41",
        "42 - 1 000 à 1 999 salariés": "42",
        "51 - 2 000 à 4 999 salariés": "51",
        "52 - 5 000 à 9 999 salariés": "52",
        "53 - 10 000 salariés et plus": "53",
        "NN - Non renseigné": "NN"
    }
    
    # Appliquer le mapping aux tranches d'effectifs du DataFrame
    selected_rows['trancheEffectifsEtablissement'] = selected_rows['trancheEffectifsEtablissement'].map(effectifs_mapping)
    
    if effectifs_box:
        selected_rows = selected_rows[selected_rows['trancheEffectifsEtablissement'].isin(effectifs_box)]
    
    return selected_rows

# Fonction pour lancer la requête et afficher le DataFrame résultant
def lancer_script():
    df = pd.read_excel(r'*************\TEST.xlsx')
    
    effectifs_indices = listbox.curselection()
    effectifs_box = [effectifs_mapping[listbox.get(index)] for index in effectifs_indices]

    print("Effectifs sélectionnés :", effectifs_box)
    print("Taille du DataFrame avant filtrage :", len(df))
    df_with_effectif_filter = select_ets_effectifs(df, effectifs_box)
    print("Taille du DataFrame filtré :", len(df_with_effectif_filter))

    if not df_with_effectif_filter.empty:
        print("Données filtrées :")
        print(df_with_effectif_filter)
    else:
        print("Aucun établissement ne correspond aux tranches d'effectifs sélectionnées.")
        
# Création de la fenêtre principale
window = Tk()
window.title("Filtrage par tranche des effectifs")

# Liste des tranches d'effectifs
effectif_list = [
    "00 - 0 salarié",
    "01 - 1 ou 2 salariés",
    "02 - 3 à 5 salariés",
    "03 - 6 à 9 salariés",
    "11 - 10 à 19 salariés",
    "12 - 20 à 49 salariés",
    "21 - 50 à 99 salariés",
    "22 - 100 à 199 salariés",
    "31 - 200 à 249 salariés",
    "32 - 250 à 499 salariés",
    "41 - 500 à 999 salariés",
    "42 - 1 000 à 1 999 salariés",
    "51 - 2 000 à 4 999 salariés",
    "52 - 5 000 à 9 999 salariés",
    "53 - 10 000 salariés et plus",
    "NN - Non renseigné"
]

# Création de la listebox et du bouton
scrollbar = Scrollbar(window)
label_listbox = Label(window, text="Tranche des effectifs")
listbox = Listbox(window, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
button_query = Button(window, text="Effectuer la requête", command=lancer_script)


# Ajouter les éléments à la liste
for item in effectif_list:
    listbox.insert(END, item)

# Disposition des widgets
label_listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)  
listbox.grid(row=1, column=0)        
scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1)      
button_query.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=0, sticky="w")

# Démarrer la boucle principale
window.mainloop()
```

**Result**

> Effectifs sélectionnés : ['01'] Taille du DataFrame avant filtrage :
> 604 Taille du DataFrame filtré : 0 Aucun établissement ne correspond
> aux tranches d'effectifs sélectionnées.

Thank you in advance.
(In case it doesn't show in my code, i'm a beginner)

Ezaan

Comment: Are you sure you've got data with 1 employee ? (Effectifs sélectionnés: ['01'])
The code works just fine for me

Comment: Slice "01" is selected from my listbox and I have "01" data in my dataframe. But the DF return is empty.
For you, this returns the rows with 01, right?

Comment: Yes I have copied your code and created my own dataframe, it works just as expected

Comment: I must be nearby then....
Can you share your file with me to study the similarities or possible differences? Thank you.

Comment: I just used `df = pd.DataFrame()

    df["trancheEffectifsEtablissement"] = ["00 - 0 salarié", "00 - 0 salarié",  "42 - 1 000 à 1 999 salariés", "42 - 1 000 à 1 999 salariés", "01 - 1 ou 2 salariés"]`

instead of the `read_excel`

Comment: Thank you for giving me an answer.
The difference is that my dataframe doesn't contain "01 - 1 to 2 employees", but only "01" codes.

I deleted my select_effectifs function and simply replaced it with this:   

effectifs_codes = [effectif_list[index].split(' - ')[0] for index in effectifs_indices]
df_with_effectif_filter = df[df['trancheEffectifsEtablissement'].isin(effectifs_codes)]

Comment: Note that if a value is not found in the map (`map(effectifs_mapping)`), it is replaced by nan. So yes if you had only '01' then it was replaced by nan thus your filter wasn't working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67826593/pandas-map-dictionary-default-missing-value