# Difference between get and dunder getitem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading Fluent Python and trying to get a deeper understanding of dictionaries.

So when I run the below, the results are easy to understand in that both get() and dunder getitem() return the same result

```
sample = {'a':1, 'b':2}
print(sample.__getitem__('a')) # 1
print(sample.get('a')) # 1
```

When I subclass dict with get(), I get a working instance

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return 0

    def get(self, key):
        return self[key]

d = MyDict(sample)
print(d['a']) # 1
print(d['c']) # 0
```

Now if I replace get() with dunder getitem() I get an error and I am unsure why.

```
class MyDict2(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return 0

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self[key]

d = MyDict2(sample)
print(d['a'])
print(d['c'])
```

error

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

So the question is, what is the difference between get and dunder getitem in this situation and why does this cause a recursion error?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2390827/8033585 for how to implement `__getitem__()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because `self[key]` in `MyDict2.__getitem__(key)` is equivalent to (i.e., calls) `self.__getitem__(key)` => infinite recursion.

Answer (score 8):

in

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self[key]
```

`self[key]` calls the lowest-level `__getitem__` which calls `self[key]` ... infinite recursion.

In:

```
def get(self, key):
    return self[key]
```

`self[key]` calls the lowest-level `__getitem__` as well but from the `dict` class, so it doesn't recurse: it works (you just overloaded the `get` method, that's all)