# How to view the source code of dict.__getitem__() method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone help to say, how to view the definition of `dict.__getitem__()` method?

Answer (score 3):

`dict.__getitem__()` is a built-in method implemented in C, the source of which can be found in CPython's `PyDict_GetItem` function:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/796cc6e3ad3617c1ea9e528663aac1a206230a28/Objects/dictobject.c#L1349

Comment: Thanks , it helped.

Comment: can you also help to find the python definition of the same dict __getitem__() method

Comment: Glad to be of help. There is no Python definition of `dict.__getitem__` because it is purely implemented in C.

Comment: ok, so what if i want to override the the same method by inheriting dict  into my class , how would i do that

Comment: There are many examples if you do a search with keywords "python dict subclass". For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict-and-override-getitem-setitem