# How to use __setitem__ properly?

Tags: python, setattr

I want to make a data object:

```
class GameData:
  def __init__(self, data={}):
    self.data = data

  def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self.data[item]

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self.data[key] = value

  def __getattr__(self, item):
    return self.data[item]

  def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    self.data[kay] = value

  def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.data)
```

When I create a GameData object, I get RecursionError. How can I avoid **setitem** recall itself?

Comment: The problem is `__setattr__`

Comment: did you mean `key` in place of `kay` at `self.data[kay] = value`

Comment: `self.__dict__['data'] = data` in `__init__` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly subclass dict and override \_\_getitem\_\_ & \_\_setitem\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict-and-override-getitem-setitem)

Comment: Beside the point, but that `__repr__` is bad. It will make it hard to debug your code if it looks like you're dealing with dicts but you're actually dealing with `GameData` instances. It would be OK as `__str__` though, I think. A good `__repr__` would be `return '{}({})'.format(type(self).__name__, str(self.data))`

Comment: Note that the problem actually has nothing to with your `__setitem__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the assignment `self.data = data`, `__setattr__` is called because `self` has no attribute called `data` at the moment. `__setattr__` then calls `__getattr__` to obtain the non-existing attribute `data`. `__getattr__` itself calls `__getattr__` again. This is a recursion.

Use `object.__setattr__(self, 'data', data)` to do the assignment when implementing `__setattr__`.

```
class GameData:
  def __init__(self, data=None):
    object.__setattr__(self, 'data', {} if data is None else data)

  def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self.data[item]

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self.data[key] = value

  def __getattr__(self, item):
    return self.data[item]

  def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    self.data[key] = value

  def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.data)
```

For details, see [the `__getattr__` manual](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)

Additionally, do not use mutable objects as default parameter because the same object `{}` in the default argument is shared between `GameData` instances.

Comment: Just curious, why do you use `object` instead of `super()`?

Comment: `super()` is a good choice, especially when inheritance is used. `object` ensure the default behavior of `__setattr__`. Updating the dict of the `__dict__` attribute can achieve the same goal as well.

Comment: Inheritance is *always* used; `GameData` inherits from `object`. Failing to use `super` means you can't (easily) use `GameData` as a base class for other classes that *do* use `super`. There's no "default" definition of `__setattr__`; just the definition you inherit from an ancestor.

Comment: Further, `__setdata__` is *always* used to set an attribute, unlike `__getattr__` which is only used to get a value for an attribute not otherwise found via the normal lookup procedure.