# Python: dictionary with promiscous key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm trying to create a dictionary with 1 key that resolves multiple keys per value

```py
my_key = 'a' or 'b'

d = {
    my_key: 'example'
}

print(d.get('a'))

>> 'example'

print(d.get('b'))

>>
```

In the second case it doesn't work.
I need to have the same value without replicating the key.

**Update**
I'm trying to avoid the usual way like Brad Day described below:

`d = {my_key1:"example", my_key2: "example"}`

Comment: If you want a value to be available under multiple keys then you need multiple keys with that value. What is the goal of this? We might be able to advise a different approach.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish. `my_key` will always be "a" in your example.

Comment: `my_key = 'a' or 'b'` is a logical statement that always returns "a". as Bafsky said. You would need a dictionary like  `d = {my_key1:"example", my_key2: "example"}`

Comment: d = {my_key1:"example", my_key2: "example"} I want to avoid that, to replicate the key. The values of the 2 keys would be the same. So as I understand in your answers this is not possible in a dictionary? I only can do this logic out of the dictionary?

Comment: You'd have to create some custom dictionary subclass that somehow stores and resolves multiple keys per value. The builtin `dict` can't do that, period.

Comment: @deceze yes probably you are right

Comment: Does [How to properly subclass dict and override __getitem__ & __setitem__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict-and-override-getitem-setitem) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about achievement but maybe if you have immutable *values* like strings and want to make sure of unified updates? I.e. that whatever you do to a’s value will be same for b?

```
di = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 1}


d = {
    1: 'example'
}

print(d[di['a']])
d[di['b']] = "modded"
print(d[di['a']])
```

### output:

```
example
modded
```