# Python dict with named key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need a very concise dict-like structure, but with named keys.
Suppose I have a value f(k, q).
I can create a nested dict like `f[0][1] = 'value'` or `f[(0,1)] = 'value'`.

But there is high probability that the user will mix up `f[0][1]` and `f[1][0]` .

Therefore, I want something like `f[k=0, q=0] = 'value'`.

If I create a class to implement it as a custom class with `f.get()` and `f.set(value)`, the code becomes much less readable, since these expressions are a part of convoluted formulas, for which readability is important, so that the 'set' should be done with the `=` operator and not by passing the value as a function parameter.

Is it possible to modify `__set__` and `__get__` magic methods to accept keyword arguments?

Comment: Would `f[key(k=0, q=0)] = 'value'` be good enough?  All you need to do is `key = collections.namedtuple("key", "k,q")`, `f` remains a plain dictionary.

Comment: Yes, it's possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict-and-override-getitem-setitem

Answer (score -1):

The closest syntax I could find involves defining your own `namedtuple`.

## Defining a key type

```py
from collections import namedtuple
Key = namedtuple("Key", ["k", "q"])
```

## Setting an item

```py
f = {}
f[Key(k=0, q=1)] = "value"
```

## Getting an item

Any of the following methods should work.

```py
f[0, 1]
f[(0, 1)]
f[Key(0, 1)]
f[Key(k=0, q=1)]
```